# Network traffic simulation with one computer

Tags: linux, networking, traffic

I have a Linux box with a gigabit Ethernet interface in a local network. With this single computer, I need to simulate HTTP traffic like if it was coming from 20 machines (hence with 20 different IP and MAC addresses) in order to stress-test a router.

I created a script which mounts 20 tun/tap devices with macvlan, but the question is, can I generate traffic through all these virtual interfaces at the same time ?

Can I achieve this with some simple scripts or do I need a specific tool or application ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try 'ab' [apache benchmark] it throws a ton of load to your http server

```
man ab
```

http://linux.die.net/man/1/ab
You should be able to work that into some scripts if you have started already.

Or, from the opposite end of the spectrum: locust - http://locust.io
its a web based load tester.

These are really for benchmarking http services, rather than routers, but the traffic has to go through the router to get to the http service :D

Comment: Thanks, I've tested 'ab' with a specific routing table to handle my bunch of MAC addresses, and it works pretty good :)